# VS Code problems regarding launching the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have activated the Run as administrator property in vs code. Then a file called cli.js is opening while I am opening vs code even after I deactivated the Run as administrator property.

I am seeking help how to prevent the cli.js file opening.